# PrimeNG add custom header text

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, primeng

How i can here add my custom header text with icons and more?

```
<p-accordion>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
   Content 1
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
    Content 2
</p-accordionTab>
<p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
    Content 3    
</p-accordionTab>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<p-accordionTab>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">Header Content</ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">Body Content</ng-template>
</p-accordionTab>
```

You can change the content